# How to remove an image in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Let's say I just add a simple little image:

```
var image = scene.add.image(200,200,'simple-little-image.png');
```

Then later, I want to destory it. Not just hide it, but remove all of it's data and everything.

I checked [the docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Image.html) and the image class doesn't have any sort of `kill` or `destroy` function. However, it has an `ignoreDestory` boolean. Which makes me think the `scene` must remove it? But I cannot find a method for removing images in the [`scene` class's docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scene.html).

And looking through the `scene` class in the console, I can't find any functions of it's children that would remove the image.

So, How do I remove the image and all of it's data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it doesn't have a `kill()`, an `Image` does in fact have a [`destroy()` method](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Image.html#destroy__anchor).

You might already be aware, but just make sure you have access to the `image` variable where you want to destroy it.

Comment: Also if you want to remove the image from the cache from within the scene `this.textures.remove('theKey')`